# How many digits can be stored for a number in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle, precision, significant-digits

I have a number from an Oracle database of 47306832975095894070.85314746810624532.  When I bring it into SQL Server, it certainly doesn't show that many digits.  It shows as 4.73068329750959E+19, and the field is defined as FLOAT.

I think that probably includes all the significant digits, but I'm being asked if the number can be stored exactly as Oracle had it.  Is there a another data type that will store ALL the digits?  Is there a way in SQL Server 2005 to display the number not in exponential, but show all the digits stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of the [NUMBER](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00222)*(p, s)* Oracle datatype on Sql Server is the [numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746(SQL.90).aspx)*(p, s)* datatype. Note that the default values for *p* (precision) and *s* (scale) are not the same on both platforms.

On Sql Server, a [float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773(SQL.90).aspx) represents a floating point number that is a whole different, [approximate representation](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2005/01/10/floating-point-arithmetic-part-one.aspx) of a number. On Oracle, the equivalent would be [BINARY_DOUBLE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i140621).

Answer (score 3):

Use decimal data type.
decimal(p,s) -  p is a precision value, s is a scale value.

Answer (score 3):

instead of float, use Decimal(38,17).  This should allow you to store the number with the same precision that you had in Oracle.